# Are there restrictions on what is a valid url or file parameter for the maven deploy plugin

Tags: java, maven, deployment, maven-deploy-plugin

I have copied the following plugins from a project with a similar layout and updated the appropriate fields. I have changed the exact names but the format including placement of "-" characters is preserved. This project builds an artifact in the "target" subdir with the name

> artifact-id-1.4.3-standalone.jar

Unless I am mistaken I believe the  param in the deploy plugin references this file and the  field is a direct copy/paste from another project which deploys to the same repo. However I get this error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.5:deploy-file (default-cli) on project kafka-mirror: The parameters 'file', 'url' for goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.5:deploy-file are missing or invalid

when running this command:

> mvn -X deploy:deploy-file

I have tried hard coding the name of the artifacts removing all substitutions but this had the same error. I have also tried looking around and have seen suggestions that URL should be the folder where the jar is. I tried that and got the same error too, but I am certain this is not right anyway as that field should be unchanged between all our other poms. I have also tried using the deploy:deploy goal but that failed with a different error. This error originally comes from Jenkins but I have replicated it on my local machine by trying to call the deploy-file goal. Any further suggestions or advice would be most appreciated.

I have attached an anonymised version of my pom plugins below.

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
      <inherited>false</inherited>
      <configuration>
        <attach>false</attach>
        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-standalone</finalName>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>net.mycompany.mygroup.MyArtifact</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>executable-jar</id>
      <phase>deploy</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>deploy-file</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <repositoryId>mycompany-releases</repositoryId>
        <groupId>net.mycompany.mygroup</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-artifact-id</artifactId>
        <classifier>standalone</classifier>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
        <generatePom>false</generatePom>
        <updateReleaseInfo>true</updateReleaseInfo>
        <url>https://maven.mycompany.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        <file>target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-standalone.jar</file>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html

Comment: I have a distribution management section with the mycompany-releases repo specified and the security details in my settings.xml. Again this is copy pasted from a working project. Is that what you were suggesting? Or are you questioning the use of the deploy-file plugin for a maven artifact? Again that is copy paste, we are using it because of the hooks built into Jenkins, it should be, and is, capable of deploying maven artifacts. What I am trying to discover is why this one does not work when all the other projects with the same style of pom do. I just used the standard template and it fails.